# A mkl version of mxnet seems not providing ndarray

Tags: mxnet

When to use mxnet-cu101mkl = {version = "==1.5.0",sys_platform = "== 'linux'"}, I get error that I cannot longer import ndarray or nd:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ndarray'
```

I have no problem with this when using the same code with mxnet-cu101 (no mkl).

Is this just a bug or is this  subpackage no longer supported?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that `mxnet-cu100mkl` works fine (version 1.5.0). Very slight CUDA version difference to yours but the package shouldn't change. I think you might be importing a different `mxnet` here, possibly a folder called `mxnet` for example. Check the following:

```
import mxnet as mx

print(mx.__file__)
```

It should show the path to mxnet within `site-packages` for you Python environment. e.g.

```
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py
```